# Huge packet loss from laptop to my WiFi modem/router

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, wifi-driver, packet-loss

I have been using a new laptop (only a few weeks old) on WiFi with no issues for a while. My laptop has now slowed to a crawl making it unusable.
I tested the connection using someone else's WiFi and had the same issue.
Now I see that I am getting huge packet losses between laptop and router on WiFi. With direct LAN connection is 100%.
I have tried rebooting router/modem, restarting laptop, flushing DSN, updated drivers, etc. nothing is working for me. Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Does this happen regardless of the proximity of the laptop to the router? It sounds like the card might be faulty or really bad quality.  (Conventional wisdom says it could be interference from other networks, its just my gut and your comment about issues on other persons wifi that makes me think otherwise)

Comment: Hi, please see if it's helpful to you:https://www.dnsstuff.com/reduce-packet-loss

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was an application at start-up (don't know which one yet). I stopped all, except Windows apps from startup task manager and after that my WiFi was back to normal..

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem child was ASUS's own app. MyAsus[ServicesRunning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnpDm.jpg)